# Default protocol implementation causes 'does not conform to protocol' error

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, protocol-oriented

I am trying to add a default implementation to one of my delegate methods. However, after adding the default implementation and removing the method from the class that implements the protocol, I get `does not conform to protocol` error. It works in a playground.

```
protocol NavigationDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didSetToolbarVisible(_ isVisible: Bool)
}
extension NavigationDelegate {
    func didSetToolbarVisible(_ isVisible: Bool) {
        print("Default implementation")
    }
}
class MyViewController: NavigationDelegate {
    // 'does not conform to protocol' error
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess, the parts from `NSObjectProtocol` - what happens if you inherit `MyViewController` from `NSObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! My `NavigationDelegate` and its extension were in a different target than the one that `MyViewController` belongs to. Simply moving the extension to the same target worked.

Hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: Instead of moving the protocol extension (ie, the default implementation) to the same target as your code that conforms to the protocol, you could just make the extension and its methods "public"

Answer (score 3):

A class does not conform to `NSObjectProtocol` by default, that causes the error.

Change

```
protocol NavigationDelegate: NSObjectProtocol
```

to

```
protocol NavigationDelegate: class
```

Comment: Same error. Even when I make it `protocol NavigationDelegate {}`

Comment: @nambatee What is the exact text of the error message?

Comment: @thekman `Type 'MyViewController' does not conform to protocol 'NavigationDelegate' Do you want to add protocol stubs?`. My `MyViewController ` inherits from Foo, which inherits from Bar (which conforms to 2 other protocols based on `NSObjectProtocol`), which inherits from UIViewController (in case it matters)

Comment: @nambatee I recreated the same scenario in an empty project and it works for me perfectly. There must be something else that causes the error.

Answer (score 2):

Your `NavigationDelegate` uses a base protocol of `NSObjectProtocol`. This means that anything that conforms to `NavigationDelegate` must also conform to `NSObjectProtocol`. Change your class declaration to the following:
`class MyViewController: NSObject, NavigationDelegate`.